# Sequence scroll animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, sequence

In the begining I have to say I am pure newbie in coding (especially in JS and jQuery) and I have a problem that I really cannot solve since few days.
I want to create sequence animation that will be animated depending on scroll position. I found the source online with the code for that **---> THIS** https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Image-Sequence-Animation-On-Scroll-Sequencer/ **<--** The thing is I have a massive problem to put them togheter...

I would love to have this scrolabble animation on the right side of the page (div called "right") but whenever I am doing this, the animation is not running...

Below you can see my code.

Would be more than happy to hear from you guys with some help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.project1').offset({
        left: e.pageX + 20,
        top: e.pageY + 20
    });
});

$(".numero1").hover(function () {
    $('.project1').css({opacity : 1.0});
  },
  function () {
    $('.project1').css({opacity : 0.0});
  }
);

});
```

```css
body {
 background-color:#ffffff;
 font:300 Arial, sans-serif;
 top:0px;
 margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 cursor: url('./img/dot1.ico'), auto;
 overflow:hidden;
}

*{
 border:none;
}

a{
text-decoration:none;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: black;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: black;
}

a:hover{
 color: black;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-style:italic;
}

.left a{
 color: black;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-style: italic;
}

.left a:hover{
 color: black;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-style: normal;
}

li {
 list-style-type: none;
}


#container {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    will-change: overflow;
}

.left,
.middle,
.right {
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: .5rem;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.left::-webkit-scrollbar,
.middle::-webkit-scrollbar,
.right::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}


.left {
 top: 15px;
 font:300 45px Arial, sans-serif, white;
 font-style: normal;
 line-height: 1em;
 color: white;
 width: 2.7%;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 margin-top: -100px;
 background-color: white; /* Old browsers */
 /* background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb2b2 0%, #849fff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
 /* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffb2b2 0%,#849fff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
 /* background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffb2b2 0%,#849fff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
 /* filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb2b2', endColorstr='#849fff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
 border-right: 0.5px solid black;
}

.middle {
    width: 28%;
 padding: 10 10 0 0;
 margin-top: -110px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 background-color: white;
 border-right: 0.5px solid black;
}

.projects img{
 width: 100%;
}

.right {
 flex: 1;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 margin-top: -100px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 font: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: white ;
 font-size: 0px;
 color: black;
}

.right img{
 width: 100%;
}


.gallery {
   margin-top: 0px;
}

.projects {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 5px;
 height: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 font:300 22px Arial, sans-serif;
 color: black;
 cursor: url('./img/dot.ico'), pointer;
 border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
}

#container figure {
 background: black;
 margin: 0px;
 line-height: 0px;
}
#container figure img {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;

}
#container figure:hover img {
 opacity: 0;
}

table .numero1{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}

table .numero2{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}

table .numero3{
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}

table .numero4{
 margin-top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}

.numero {
 padding-right: 1%;
 margin-top: -5px;
 width:5%;
 font-size: 33px;
 /* -webkit-text-stroke: 0.5px black;*/
}

.title {
 padding-left: 3%;
 width: 40%;
 padding-right: 1%;
}

.type {
 width: 30%;
 padding-left: 10%;
}

.year {
 width: 5%;
 padding-left: 1%;
}

.project1 {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: 9999;
 opacity: 0;
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Name</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="icon" href="./img/sm.png" type="image/gif" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
<div id="container">

 <div class="left">
  <a style="cursor: url('./img/dot.ico'), pointer;" href="index.html">N<br>A<br>M<br>E</a>

 </div>

 <div class="middle">
  <div class="gallery">
   <img class="project1" src="img/project01.jpg" alt="project1">
   <div class="projects">
    <table class="numero1">
     <td></td>
     <tr><td valign="top" class="year">0</td>
      <td valign="top" class="title"><a>title</a></td>
      <td valign="top" class="type">what is it</td>
     </tr>
         </table>
   </div>
   <img class="project1" src="img/project01.jpg" alt="project1">
  <div class="projects">
   <table class="numero1">
    <td></td>
    <tr><td valign="top" class="year">0</td>
     <td valign="top" class="title"><a>title</a></td>
     <td valign="top" class="type">what is it</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <img class="project1" src="img/project01.jpg" alt="project1">
  <div class="projects">
   <table class="numero1">
    <td></td>
    <tr><td valign="top" class="year">0</td>
     <td valign="top" class="title"><a>title</a></td>
     <td valign="top" class="type">what is it</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <img class="project1" src="img/project01.jpg" alt="project1">
  <div class="projects">
   <table class="numero1">
    <td></td>
    <tr><td valign="top" class="year">0</td>
     <td valign="top" class="title"><a>title</a></td>
     <td valign="top" class="type">what is it</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <img class="project1" src="img/project01.jpg" alt="project1">
  <div class="projects">
   <table class="numero1">
    <td></td>
    <tr><td valign="top" class="year">0</td>
     <td valign="top" class="title"><a>title</a></td>
     <td valign="top" class="type">what is it</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>

  <div class="right">






  </div>
 </div>

 
</body>
```

Comment: Provide a js Fiddle of this problem.

Comment: Hey @ChinmoySamanta 
https://jsfiddle.net/3m0a2ptL/1/  there is it